# Center positioning of a modal using fixed: how to also allow vertical scroll?

Tags: css, position

I have a modal window popping up, which I want to center relative to the reader's position on the page. The best way to achieve this seems to be with the position fixed/top 50% fix:

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

So far so good, the modal pops up in precise center. See jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cbqN2/

But I want my users to be able to scroll the modal if the content is too long for their screens:
http://jsfiddle.net/xwhMa/1

Any way to achieve this, by nesting divs with different positions, or JQuery as a last resort?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it's definitely going to need JavaScript (and therefore you should use jQuery).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but try this:

```
ul li {font-size:23px}
.fixed {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    **overflow-y:scroll**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/cbqN2/3/

having your modal have a container that holds the content and clips it at a fixed height? then the user can scroll in the modal, instead of worrying about a jQuery solution to scroll the outside the modal until it hits the bottom, then stick to the bottom, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a peculiarity of `position: fixed` :) which is .. well, to always stay fixed on the screen. If you want it to appear in the center but move when a user scrolls the page simply use `position: absolute;` not `fixed`. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/cbqN2/2/

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make an absolutely positioned div appear "relative" to the portion of the page currently in focus? 

To answer my own question: I guess I could have the absolute positioning values produced via JQuery, and the user would still be able to scroll. Will try that.